# What does chief nobody mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is "chief nobody" a mistake, I wonder?

> Mark S. McNally is the **founder and chief nobody** of Nobody Studios, a globally distributed high-velocity venture studio bringing together investors, founders and creatives to forge companies with purpose, real-world value and a human connection.

Source: [Emerging Investment Trends To Watch In 2022](https://www.ibtimes.com/emerging-investment-trends-watch-2022-3359203) by Mark McNally

Comment: It's a facetious usage (maybe not a "one-off", but certainly not well-established). But it's probably equivalent to the [well-established](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chief_cook_and_bottle_washer#:~:text=chief%20cook%20and%20bottle%20washer%20(plural%20chief%20cooks%20and%20bottle,lowest%20(bottle%20washer)%20quotations%20%E2%96%BC) facetious usage [***chief cook and bottle washer***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22chief+cook+and+bottle+washer%22).

Answer (score 2):

The term "chief nobody" has no established meaning outside of context. If I saw it in an article that was disparaging of its subject I would assume it was an insult, meaning roughly "someone who has an important title but actually doesn't do anything important."

The passage you quote is **not** part of an article but rather is the "about the author" blurb, a little piece of biography used to give some context on who the author is and why they should be trusted. It is written in the third person, which imitates the short author biographies found on book dust jackets.

But unlike book-jacket biographies, which are usually written by the publisher, it is nearly certain that Mark McNally wrote this blurb himself. (You can also find this in theatrical playbills, where the actors will write their own third-person biographies.) He says that he is the founder of Nobody Studios, and that he is "chief nobody." (If you visit the company's website you will see the term stylized with capitals: "Chief Nobody.") What exactly this means is unclear, but it is obviously *not* an insult; given the name of the company, and the fact that he is the founder of the company, it probably means that he is in charge of the company—akin to "President" or "Chief Executive Officer."

The term may be a play on some concept within the company, for example the company may have the idea that *the ideas people have are more important than who the people are*, thus everyone who works at the company is a "nobody" and McNally is the "Chief Nobody." But you would have to ask him to tell you what exactly he means, because it is not a standard term.